# Error in parsing XML file with encoding UTF-8 and UTF-16

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, xml-parsing

I am using below method to parse an XML file -

```
package com.kcs.xml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class ParseXMLOld {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final String FILE_PATH="C:\\abc.xml";
        File file=new File(FILE_PATH);
        ParseXMLOld pxo=new ParseXMLOld();
        pxo.parseUTFXML(file);
    }

    public Document parseUTFXML(File file) 
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder=null;
        Document doc=null;
        try {
            docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-16");
            InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
            is.setEncoding("UTF-16");
            doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
            System.out.println("Done");
            } 
        catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        finally
            {
            docBuilderFactory=null;
            docBuilder=null;
            }
    return doc;
    }
}
```

I have two file with encoding UTF-8 and UTF-16. If value of "UTF_ENCODING" in above code is UTF-8 then the file with "UTF-8" encoding works fine. But my code fails to parse other file with encoding "UTF-16" and vice versa.

I would like to mention one more interesting thing, if I create an sample XML file manually with encoding UTF-16, IE7 fails to open it. But the file with UTF-16 encoding, that I am trying to parse (I am getting it from another system) is opening in IE7. But if you edit the first line of this file (change encoding to UTF-8 and then change it to UTF-16 again), it doesn't open. I have no idea why this is happening.

Please help.

I dont know how I can share these file. If required please tell me how can I share these two files?

**For example, how can I parse below file?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
  <Details>
    <Content>
      <id>1234¥£€$¢</id>
      <Valid_From_Date>2013-01-01</Valid_From_Date>
      <Valid_To_Date>9999-12-31</Valid_To_Date>
      <Company>1210</Company>
      <Description>2nd Life Transaction</Description>
    </Content>
    <Totals>
      <Count>1</Count>
    </Totals>
</Details>
```

I am getting below error -

[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:251)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
    at com.kcs.xml.ParseXMLOld.parseUTF8XML(ParseXMLOld.java:34)
    at com.kcs.xml.ParseXMLOld.main(ParseXMLOld.java:19)

Answer (score 1):

The following works of me if the files either have a BOM or the encoding specified in the preamble:

```
 File fXmlFile = … ;
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(fXmlFile))
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But this doesn't work if XML file contains any UTF-8 character for example "¥£€$¢₡". Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Do you have an example file?

Comment: Yes, I have few files. Can I share here somehow? You can enter above characters under any tag and try to parse it.

Comment: The following files https://github.com/marschall/dropbox/raw/master/utf8-bom.xml https://github.com/marschall/dropbox/raw/master/utf16-bom.xml work for me with the code provided.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in case it doesn't contain BOM character, then it fails. To test it just copy paste the posted XML. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: UTF-16 always needs to BOM to know whether it's LE or BE. For UTF-8 the BOM is optional if you have a preamble.